# No new migration for subclass of subclass of a field

Tags: python, django, migration

I have the following setup (Django 2.0.6, also in 2.2), the first migration is with the field having `max_length=64` and now I want to change the `DummyCharField.max_length` to 255:

```py
class BaseDummyCharField(models.CharField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'max_length' not in kwargs:
            kwargs['max_length'] = 64
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class DummyCharField(BaseDummyCharField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['max_length'] = 255
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class AnotherDummyCharField(BaseDummyCharField):
    ...


class DummyModel(models.Model):
    dummy = DummyCharField()
```

When running `makemigrations`, it just says "No changes detected".

I also tried using `deconstruct()` as told in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-model-fields/#field-deconstruction), but it still didn't work.

```py
class DummyCharField(BaseDummyCharField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['max_length'] = 255
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()
        del kwargs['max_length']
        return name, path, args, kwargs
```

As a workaround I made the following:

```py
class DummyCharField(BaseDummyCharField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # If wrapped inside an `if`, it works...
        if 'max_length' not in kwargs:
            kwargs['max_length'] = 255
        ...
```

Am I missing something here or what exactly is my fault in this case?

Comment: You are doing everything correctly. maybe your ```APP``` is missing in ```INSTALLED_APPS```.

Comment: @gachdavit my `APP` is present in `INSTALLED_APPS`, the initial migration was created and everything. And if I put in the workaround as seen above, the new migration is also created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. Intro

You were using the **`__init__()`** method in wrong way.
While Django's **`makemigrations`** command, it analyzing the changes made by us. During the process, it calls the `__init__()` methods to generate the old-parameter and new parameters. (here, old param is **`max_length=64`** and new param is **`max_length=256`**)

---

### 2. Culprit?

The statement, **`kwargs['max_length'] = 255`** in **`__init__()`** method.
The Model Field is initialized with  **`max_length=255` everytime** which caused an ***overwrite*** here. While detecting the model changes, this statement causes **No Changes**, since you were set `max_length` to a **"CONSTANT"**.

---

### 3. Solution?

Simply put a **`if..`** condition in **`__init__()`** method.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if 'max_length'  not in kwargs:
        kwargs['max_length'] = 255
```

---

### 4. Final Code Snippet

```
class DummyCharField(BaseDummyCharField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('max_length', 123)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

---

### 5. References--[source code]

1. [**`makemigrations`** command module](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py)
2. [detecting any changes](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py#L166-L169)
3. [**`changes()`**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py#L37) method of **`MigrationAutodetector`** class
4. [**`_detect_changes()`**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py#L103) method of **`MigrationAutodetector`** class
5. [**`generate_altered_fields()`**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py#L904) method of **`MigrationAutodetector`** class
6. [**`deep_deconstruct()`**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py#L49) method of **`MigrationAutodetector`** class